# How to put an ImageButton above a centered ImageButton in a relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` centered in it I have an `ImageButton` centered. I want another to the right of the first one, but it appears way off to the left of the screen, although aligned to the top.

I used a relative layout because I want the buttons relative to each other. *(Was this wrong?)*

I have four buttons in total.

```
#1 centered.
#2 to the right of #1
#3 above #2
#4 to the left of #3
```

like so

```
.................
.               .
.       43      .
.       12      .
.               .
.................
```

Where #1 is smack in the middle. Currently it looks like this:

```
.................
.               .
.43             .
. 2     1       .
.               .
.................
```

- What am I doing wrong?

Here is the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/board_id"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg480x800"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dp" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/game_choice_6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/game_choice_4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/game_choice_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/game_choice_1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/game_choice_4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/game_choice_2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/game_choice_5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/game_choice_3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/game_choice_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/square_layout_id"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/game_choice_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/square_layout_id" />

<com.brdgms.android.SquareLayout
    android:id="@+id/square_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#00000000" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/game_board"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="game Board"
            android:src="@drawable/game_board" />

        <com.brdgms.android.games.game.GameBoardView
            android:id="@+id/game_canvas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_game_player_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/game_player_1_button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_game_player_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_game_player_1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_game_player_1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_game_player_1"
            android:src="@drawable/game_player_2_button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_game_player_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button_game_player_2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_game_player_2"
            android:src="@drawable/game_player_3_button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_game_player_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_game_player_3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_game_player_3"
            android:src="@drawable/game_player_4_button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.brdgms.android.SquareLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use a relative layout? Use linear layout instead. Make it horizontal and set "android:gravity" on the linearlayout to center.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/some_drawable"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/some_drawable"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your current layout file. I need to know how you had embed the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.....

```
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/button_1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:src="@drawable/image1" />          //--your image

    <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/button_2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_1"
     android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_1"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_1"
     android:src="@drawable/image1" />         //--your image

    <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/button_3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/button_2"
     android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_1"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_1"
     android:src="@drawable/image1" />         //--your image

    <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/button_4"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/button_1"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_3"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_3"
     android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button_3"
     android:src="@drawable/image1" />        //--your image

</RelativeLayout>
```

output...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by changing

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

in the inner RelativeLayout.

It wasn't about the buttons, but about the layout. :-/

Answer (score 0):

layout xml code:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_1" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/button_2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/button_1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button_1"/>
```

Here is the preview:

[image: preview]